# rewrite rule pattern can't work right

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i tried to rewrite profile.php?id=1&email=medicalboy@gmail.com  to something like that regex/profile/9/medicalboy@gmail.com

but the rule didn't work:

this is what i did

php:

```
<a href="profile/<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>/<?=$row['email']; ?>"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></a><br />
```

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /regex/
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ profile.php?id=$1&email=$2 [L]
```

what's the problem? i read carefully about rewriting but i don't know where is the problem

Comment: I'm not sure if it would cause you a serious problem, but you cannot use the `@` character in a url. Apart from that, what exactly is the problem, do you have any error messages on the screen or in the error log?

Comment: no errors,the page is blank,i used the previous one as an example not to build something really,
---------
q:is $_GET can't work to get the value from url before rewriting?

Answer (score 0):

i knew the answer

i thought if $_GET will work with uri like regex/profile/1/66
so $_GET can't get information depend on uri

so i used the explode() to get the id as like that:

```
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$exp=explode("/",$url);
$id=$exp[3];
$query=$db->query("select * from users where userid='$id'");
```